# Font Awesome Icon when background-image not available

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am searching for a simple solution to show an Font Awesome icon if the Image is not not available. I am using the following markup:

```
<div class="notAvailableIcon" style="background-image:NotAvailable.jpg">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.notAvailableIcon:before {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   content: "\f000";
 }
```

This works fine if the Image is not available. But if the image is available, the icon is still visible and in front of the image. Is there any CSS solution to hide the icon if the background-image is set or can I stack background-images, so that it is behind the image if available?

Comment: i think you are looking for this? http://jsbin.com/vogakicuyite/1/edit

Comment: set `.notAvailableIcon { z-index:0 } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may or may not fit your needs but one solution would be positioning the pseudo-element `absolute`ly and give a negative `z-index` value to it:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/qaniwo/1/edit)** *(Toggle the `background` within CSS panel)*

```css
.notAvailableIcon { position: relative; min-height: 1.2em; }

.notAvailableIcon:before {
    content: "\f000";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute; z-index: -1;
 }
```

**Side-note:** sine the pseudo-element is removed from normal flow, it's better to set a minimum height to the container, equal to the height of one line of text: `min-height: 1.2em;`

Comment: generally it works, but only if the container has no background-color set. Any idea  how to solve this? [http://jsbin.com/sisuheyexibi/1/](http://jsbin.com/sisuheyexibi/1/)

Comment: @JanHommes Then you could set the `background-color` to the pseudo-element itself rather than the container: http://jsbin.com/qaniwo/2/edit I've used the `::before` pseudo-element for both background color and the font icon, you could use `::after` to apply the background if needed so, but make sure that it would have a lower `z-index` value than `::before`.